# Can we find appropriate bases such that the matrix of a linear map is a row-echelon matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $V$ and $W$ be two finite-dimensional vector spaces over $\mathbb{F}$ and $T: V \to W$ be a linear map. Is it possible for the matrix of this linear map to be a row echelon matrix by choosing appropriate ordered bases $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{B}'$ of $V$ and $W$ respectively?

So, I can find a case where this is possible for a particular $V$ and $W$, but I am not able to generalize it. The example I found was $V = W$, and $T =$  the identity map (not doing anything, basically).

Since the question really boils down to the choice of ordered bases, I'm unsure where to begin. Any hints/help would be appreciated.

Comment: The answer is yes, this is precisely what row reduction does. Say that $T$ is represented by a matrix $X$ in some basis $A$ of $W$ and $B$ of $V$. Doing row reduction finds an elementary matrix $E$ such that $EX$ is in reduced form. Treat $E$ as a change of basis matrix acting on the basis $A$ to get a basis $A’$ in which the matrix of $T$ is $EX$.

Comment: Do you mean an invertible matrix $P$ such that $PX$ is in the reduced form? $P$ need not be elementary. Great idea otherwise, completely solves it! Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, sorry - $P$ will be a _product_ of elementary matrices, probably not elementary itself.

Comment: Cool! You could add this as an answer if you wish.